# My question is about differential amplifier. I don`t know \$2\frac{\Delta R}{R}\$ proof

Tags: differential-amplifier

[image]

My question is about differential amplifier. I don`t know \$2\frac{\Delta R}{R}\$ proof.

[image]
[image]

I don't know this proof. Why \$Av(cm) = 2 \frac{\Delta R}{R}\$?
This is my solution.
[image]

Comment: Conditions must be added.  1.R1=R_1
2. R2=R_2

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Have you tried to solve this yourself? Please show us your work so far.

Comment: It's not a homework.
I thought it was easy, so I did it myself, but it was harder than I thought, so I asked

Comment: Is there a definition of $\Delta R$?

Comment: There is no definition of $\Delta R$.